# Get sidebars depending on page

Tags: sidebar

Is there a way to get only the sidebars used on a particular page?

Using:

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
$widget_map = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
```

Can get me all of the sidebars, but I'm interested in getting the sidebars only for a particular page. Something sounding like `get_sidebars_by_page_id()`

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean get specific widget area from a page? Sometime ago, I created a theme where every page had its own widget area dynamically, so "about page" had a "About" widget area etc. (Please do not use `wp_get_sidebars_widgets` is deprecated.)

Comment: The function `wp_get_sidebars_widgets` isn't deprecated, the codex is referring to its parameter that is deprecated.  I mean getting the sidebar IDs of a page if I only know the page object.